# How to redirect to another page when drop button is selected with flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, flask

I'm very new to html and flask. In webapp it contents select dropdown button how can I redirect to other page when dropdown button is selected below are my code

html code

```
<form action="/gallery_new/folder_path" method="post">
    <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" onchange="checkAlert(event)" name="cadlists">
        <option selected>Select label type </option>
        {% for image_name in image_names %}
        <option value={{image_name}}>{{image_name}}</option>
        {%endfor%} 
      </select>

    </form>


<script>function checkAlert(evt){
        console.log(evt.target.value)
    }
    </script>
```

Flask code

```
@app.route('/gallery_new/<folder_path>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_gallery_new(folder_path):
    all_imgs = os.listdir(folder_path)
    all_imgs_val = 0
    img_paths = os.listdir(os.path.join(folder_path,all_imgs[all_imgs_val]))
    cls_name = all_imgs[all_imgs_val]
    return render_template('gallery.html',image_names = all_imgs,img_paths=img_paths,folder_path=folder_path,cls_name=cls_name)
```

when I choose option in select button it wont redirect to the page I want.
How can I modify this code to achieve what I want? any help or suggestion on this will be very helpful

Comment: What is your `checkAlert(event)` function doing ? Since it is called by onchange event, it could end by `window.location` that redirects to the correct link

Comment: ok.I tried that but I couldnt redirect to other page using checkAlert .I've edited my qsn including this please check

Answer (score 1):

I was initially thinking of something along the lines of `window.location.replace("{{ url_for('get_gallery_new') }}");`, but I honestly dont know how to use parameters with this.

Another solution is to submit your form: since the proper option is selected. Give your form and ID, then you can select your form and finally call [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

```html
<form action="{{url_for('get_gallery_new')}}" method="post" id="myForm">
    <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" onchange="checkAlert(event)" name="cadlists">
        <option selected>Select label type </option>
        {% for image_name in image_names %}
        <option value={{image_name}}>{{image_name}}</option>
        {%endfor%} 
    </select>
</form>


<script>
    function checkAlert(evt){
        console.log(evt.target.value);
        myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

And in the Flask code you can retrieve the `select` value with this after importing request (`from flask import request`)

```py
@app.route('/gallery_new', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_gallery_new():

    folder_path = request.form.get('cadlists')

    all_imgs = os.listdir(folder_path)
    all_imgs_val = 0
    img_paths = os.listdir(os.path.join(folder_path,all_imgs[all_imgs_val]))
    cls_name = all_imgs[all_imgs_val]
    return render_template('gallery.html',image_names = all_imgs,img_paths=img_paths,folder_path=folder_path,cls_name=cls_name)
```

Comment: THanks, this worked suppose If i want to concatenate string to select value how can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt understand wich string you want to concatenate, but you can use `+` operator with string, if it is relevant ...

Comment: suppose if i want to concatenate variable which I'm obtaining from render_template folder_path with variable myForm in js . How can I do that ? I tried with + operator I was getting folder_path is underfined error

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand you question at all, `render_template` is a flask function, how can you retrieve a path from it ? And with what do you want to concatenate it ? `folder_path` is a string, so you can concatenate it with any string ...

Comment: I want to concatenate with the string value that I'm obtaining from render_template value which is folder_path challenging is how can I use this value in java script I tried as myForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); myForm = myForm+{{folder_path}} but I got error folder_path couldn't be found and syntax error

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use this value straight in JavaScript. However, you could add a function at gallery.html `onload` event, and you send your parameter as `{{folder_path}}` which is Jinja's way of using the parameters from return_template. Example : `<body onload="printFolder({{folder_path}})">.